# How to push a string to top of Auto-Filter list in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

As you see on the picture below I have some cells marked as ".check":

[image]

I would like to have this cells at the top of Auto-Filter list. See example below:

[image]

It works for alphabetical data but doesn't for alpha-numeric data. The only solution I found so far was to mark the cells with "0" but that can be misinterpreted with real 0 value. I tried all the special characters etc. but Excel always puts the cell after numeric values.

Comment: Can you simply convert the numbers to string? Instead of having 409831, have '409831 or ="409831"? Or you could add an adjecent helper column on which you would base you filter and add all the invisible special characters to sort the display filter.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I have to leave data format as it is so no conversion possible. I have multiple columns like that so no helper columns as well. There has to be simpler solution?

Comment: Here's a similar thing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214282 . But they suggest using a helper column. I think they might not be an easy way around it.

Comment: Thanks man. I hope someone will come up with easier solution